# is boiling point a colligative property?

Tags: solutions

I know that elevation in boiling point is a colligative property .But is elevation in boiling point a colligative property ? Boiling point should be a colligative property acc to me bcz it depends only on number of solute particles but many people say its not a colligative property . 1m Urea and 1 m Sugar solution have same boiling point as solvent is same (water)

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what exactly you are asking? It is quite unclear as of now.

Answer (score 1):

The colligative property is 'elevation in the boiling point.' as you have correctly pointed out. The key idea to me is that the colligative property is a comparision between a solution and the pure solvent.

However, the concept of 'boiling point' is not a colligative property. It is considered a 'physical property.' Other examples pf physical properties are 'freezing point,' 'density,' and 'viscosity.' The concept of 'boiling point' isn't a comparison in the same way a colligative property is.